# In Chaplin.js, how do I persist an object to the mediator?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, mediator, chaplinjs

I've seen many examples in the Chaplin.js docs, which imply that a model/object can be persisted on the mediator in the following fashion:

via https://github.com/chaplinjs/facebook-example/blob/master/coffee/controllers/session_controller.coffee

`createUser: (userData) ->
  mediator.user = new User userData`

In my application, whenever I attempt to set a user model as a property on mediator, the property does not persist between routes.  For example, in @onSessionSaveSuccess I assign a user to the mediator, however, after redirecting to the DashboardController, and attempting to access the mediator.user, I receive `undefined`.

```
AuthController = require 'controllers/auth-controller'
SiteView = require 'views/site-view'
LoginView = require 'views/login/login-view'
Session = require 'models/session'
User = require 'models/user'
mediator = require 'mediator'

module.exports = class SessionController extends AuthController

  initialize: ->
    @subscribeEvent 'login', @triggerLogin
    @subscribeEvent 'logout', @triggerLogout

  beforeAction: ->
    super
    @reuse 'site', SiteView

  index: (params, route, options) ->
    if @authenticated()
      Chaplin.utils.redirectTo 'dashboard#index'
    else
      @view = new LoginView region: 'main'
      @view.displayErrors() if params.error

  logout: (params, route, options) ->
    @triggerLogout()

  triggerLogin: (options) ->
    if @authenticated()
      Chaplin.utils.redirectTo 'dashboard#index'
    else
      @session.save
        userId: options.username
        password: options.passphrase
      ,
        success: @onSessionSaveSuccess
        error: @onSessionSaveError

  triggerLogout: ->
    $.removeCookie 'userId'
    $.removeCookie 'accessToken'
    @session = new Session
    @session.destroy()

  onSessionSaveSuccess: (model, response, options) ->
    if /error|failure/i.test response.status
      Chaplin.utils.redirectTo 'session#index', error: true
    else if /success/i.test response.status
      $.cookie('userId', model.get('userId'), path: '/')
      $.cookie('accessToken', model.get('token'), path: '/')
      @user = new User model.attributes
      mediator.user = @user
      Chaplin.utils.redirectTo 'dashboard#index'

  onSessionSaveError: (model, response, options) ->
    Chaplin.utils.redirectTo 'session#index', error: true
```

Please help me understand how I am misusing this pattern.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via @paulmillr —

[@theMTA](https://twitter.com/theMTA) mediator is sealed in Application#initMediator method. I suggest you to override it like here https://t.co/3Zfgp8t86s

— Paul Miller (@paulmillr) [April 8, 2014](https://twitter.com/paulmillr/statuses/453346107113086976)